# What is the best word for "kitchen products" on an e-commerce website?

Tags: orthography

I am wondering what the best word is for all things used in the kitchen, including:

- kitchen gadgets
- dishes
- pans
- forks, knives..
- kitchen towels
- kitchen decorations

What is the best word to sum it all up?

- kitchen products?
- kitchen things?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[kitchenware](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kitchenware?s=t):

> 1. Cooking equipment or utensils.

Answer (score 5):

***Culinary*** is, I think, the answer. It refers to things related to a kitchen or cookery. It is also used as the adjective of kitchen itself.

Comment: Culinary isn't also an adjective. It is only an adjective. It isn't a noun. So culinary, I think, ... no, I know, ... is not the answer to the question "what is the best word for all things used in a kitchen." "Culinary things" would be somewhat of an answer, but it is not the best WORD.

Comment: @CanisLupus in Gaurav's defense, you can just as well use adjectives in an e-commerce categorization. An adjective isn't less of word than a noun.

Comment: I think in an e-commerce sites would prefer crispy and single word names instead of cumbrous constructions. "Culinary" may be read as "Culinary Section/Corner" where 'section / corner' is understood. Thanks Pierre Arlaud.

Answer (score 4):

*[Utensils](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/utensil)*:

> noun
>
> A tool, container, or other article, especially for household use:

Comment: I typically don't refer to dishes and pans as "utensils" (southern US)

Comment: I wouldn't either (NE USA), but as part of a larger class of items it seems appropriate.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann At a push I might refer to most of those things as 'utensils' includng the crockery and cutlery. However I can't imagine describing towels or decorations as utensils. For me 'utensils' are pieces of hardware used for cooking. Even the crockery and cutlery are doubtful, pieces of fabric and items with no function are certainly not utensils.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a coined single word, consider something like:

**Culinariana** combining *culinarian* with the suffix *-ana* from

> *culinarian*: a cook or a chef

and

> *-ana* (or *-iana*): denoting an assembly of items, as household objects, art, books, or maps, or a description of such items, as a bibliography, all of which are representative of or associated with the place, person, or period named by the stem: "Americana; Shakespeareana; Victoriana."

or

**Epicureana** (or **epicuriana**), combining *epicure* or *epicurean* with the suffix *-ana/-iana*:

> *epicure* - a person who cultivates a refined taste, especially in food and wine; connoisseur.

(Definitions from Dictionary.com)

Comment: nice. knew word of the day!

Comment: I could get used to the sound of that.

Comment: or the already in-use word [culinarian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culinarian).

Comment: @erich As a noun, that would be the chef or cook, and doesn't encompass "all things used in a kitchen". Your link doesn't include the adjective form, but the adjective means "or or related to a kitchen or cookery" (for which "culinary" also would work). I don't think either definition of culinary (the noun or the adjective) really works to describe "things used in a kitchen".

Comment: alas, thou art correct.

Answer (score 1):

Although is sounds broader, the term "housewares" generally refers to stuff you'd find in the kitchen.

Comment: Umm, no.  http://www.overstock.com/Home-Garden/Housewares/31/dept.html

Comment: @PopMachine - 1. Overstock.com is not an authority on the English Language. 2. Most of those items would usually be classified as Small Appliances. 3. Most dictionaries seem to be in agreement with my personal experience, i.e., selling housewares.

Comment: True, Overstock.com isn't an English language authority, but it is a successful e-commerce website. In the context of this question it shouldn't be disregarded, and in the context of ELL it shouldn't be used as an argument against a grammatical idea on its own.

Comment: @Oldbag:  As talrnu points out, the question is about using a term on an e-commerce website, and when I googled it, this was the largest most successful e-commerce website that showed up.   It doesn't matter what a dictionary or your real-world experience says if this is real onsite usage.   It should also be pointed out:   you yourself said "although it sounds broader" -- well, if your customers are not going to expect it to means what it does mean, then it's not a good term to use when you are ***trying to sell stuff***.   It doesn't matter what your dictionary says.

Comment: I understood (or, misunderstood) that the OP was looking for a word to summarize the product line.  (In which case, the word I offered is the most common industry term.)  If OP is actually looking for a term to help sell the stuff, I'd suggest "Bridal Registry" - then, implement one.

Answer (score 1):

Cutlery or kitchen ware is the correct word I think.

Comment: its true - cutlery is cutlery no matter what its location

Answer (score 0):

There's Batterie de Cuisine (fr, lit, "Kitchen Artillery")

But Kitchenware and Cookware are pretty universal.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batterie_de_cuisine